# create index of column when same row cell of another column has today's date

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

I would like to create an index when cell in another column matches **today's** date. Here is my try for D2:

```
=index($A2:$B14, match(today(),$A2:$A14,false ),1)
```

What am I doing wrong?
[image: Table + formula]

Here is the desired Result:
[image: Image for desired Result]

Comment: What result do you get in `D2`?  If it's `#N/A` then either column A in Date and Time formatted to show just the date, or column A is strings that only look like dates

Comment: I am not sure what is going on. I tried in another sheet and it worked for the first row, but now i noticed it is not skipping the rows which do not have today's date. thoughts?  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19KbfzVnT9SybRtp8iTmcI79HNk42MwLC63yeWL9uXps/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: As you copy down the rows are updating, so the formula in `D12` is `=index($A12:$B24, match(today(),$A12:$A24,false ),2)` and Today's date is not in that range, hence the `#N/A`.  Is that what you wanted?

Comment: I wanted to get a list of just the ones that had today's date, and ignore the other ones whihc is why i used Index in this case. not right?

Comment: It's really not clear what you are trying to achieve.  Perhaps edit your Q to include a mock-up of your expected results

Comment: Hey @chrisneilsen I have added a image to the Q.

Comment: Those are the results my formula produces, suggest to validate the date of your machine, see edit to my answer...

Comment: That's what @EEM 's answer will give you. Is that somehow not what you want?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the Group of items with `Created Time = Today()` then enter this formula in `E2:E14`:

```
=IF(A2=TODAY(),B2,"")
```

Now if what you need is just a list of the Groups with today date enter this formula in `F2:F14`:

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX($B$2:$B$14,
AGGREGATE(15,6,
(1+ROW($A$2:$A$14)-ROW($A$2))/($A$2:$A$14=TODAY()),
ROWS($A2:$A$2))),"")
```

[image]

**EDIT TO HANDLE DATE WITH TIME**
If the created time contains also `hh:mm:ss` then need to adjust the formula as follows:
First formula:

```
=IF(INT($A2)=TODAY(),$B2,"")
```

Second formula:

```
=IFERROR(
INDEX($B$2:$B$16,
AGGREGATE(15,6,
(1+ROW($A$2:$A$16)-ROW($A$2))/(INT($A$2:$A$16)=TODAY()),
ROWS($A2:$A$2))),"")
```

[image]
*Fig.2*

How ever this does not account for the results shown by OP. I suggest to validate the date of the OP's machine by just entering this formula in any other cell: `=TODAY()`

Comment: Not sure why this did not work for me. I even tried formatting A column to short date.

Comment: Have not idea, perhaps the date of your machine is not tuned, enter this formula in any cell to validate the date of your machine `=Today()`. I just noticed that your dates may contain also time, so see the edit to take care of this.